# Jquery Datepicker Popover is hidden

Tags: jquery, css

I'm creating a form using Contact form 7. When a user clicks the date field a jQuery UI datepicker pops up but it is semi-hidden underneath the fields below. 
(See below image as example)

[image]

What do I need to add to the CSS that makes the jQuery UI datepicker appear completely visible over the fields below?

Here is the CSS I'm using for the Text Fields, let me know if I need to include any other css.

```
#contact li .text{
   background: #F0EFEF;
   padding:15px 10px 10px 0;
   position:absolute;
   z-index:100;
   min-width:85px;
   border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
   -moz-border-radius-bottomright:5px;
   -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
   border-top-left-radius: 5px;
   -moz-border-radius-topleft:5px;
   -webkit-border-top-left-radius:5px;
   text-indent: 5px;
}
```

Comment: You were right! I actually increased the z-index from 1 to 100 in the "ui-datepicker-div" and it works, Thank you.

Comment: Yes, specifically I edited the the element.style to z-index: 100; in the ui-datepicker-div

Comment: Okay, I got the answer posted. Glad I could help!

Comment: Hey, homey, if you're still there, I posted my answer a few days back. Thought you might upvote or accept if it was helpful to you. Glad you got it working!

Answer (score 0):

jQuery UI's CSS has no `z-index` specified for the `.ui-datepicker` class. Add `z-index: 101` or higher to keep the date picker on top.

Answer (score 0):

Is the z-index of #contact li .text interfering? Try lowering that z-index if you can. The UI Datepicker uses it's own CSS files (as I'm sure you know) and may be in conflict with this.

Try adding a z-index to the UI datepicker higher than 100 or lower the z-index in your CSS.

The element should be `ui-datepicker-div`